# VBA Open most recent file in sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, macos, sharepoint

I am writing a macro to pull together data from different places each day. I would like to include data which is uploaded to a Sharepoint site. A new file is uploaded weekly, so I want the macro to find the most recent file in that folder.

I've tried the below code but a get runtime error 52 (Bad name). I have tried removing the https:, changing to backslash, as I saw this on google but still not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
'find & open latest XYZ File
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date

MyPath = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/group/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FMC%5FStockControllersandSupplyChain%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2FSupply%20Headlines&p=true&ga=1"

'MyPath = Replace(MyPath, "/", "\")        'adaptation attempt for SharePoint folder
'MyPath = Replace(MyPath, "https:", "")  'adaptation attempt for SharePoint folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsm")

If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No XYZ files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If
    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
```

Comment: Are you missing a quote at the end of that long line?

Comment: I think you'll want to also `Replace` your %20's with spaces, %2f with a forward slash etc..

Comment: I don't think there's any reliable way to use Dir() on a http Sharepoint path, even after converting it to a UNC path.